# Не запускается реакт приложение с полем proxy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, express, backend

Добрый день или же вечер, когда я пытался связать бек и фронт(бек я писал на express.js, а фронт на реакте), и попытался добавить в package.json поле proxy со значением "http://localhost:5000", то вылетает такая ошибка:

```
Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options.allowedHosts[0] should be a non-empty string.
```

Вот что у меня на реакте написано:

```
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
    export default function App() {

        useEffect(() => {
            fetch('/messages')
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(res => console.log(res))
                .catch(err => console.error(err))
        }, [])

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Привет мир!</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Вот что в беке:

```
    import express from 'express'

    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
    const app = express()
    const messages = []

    app.use(express.json())

    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Server has been started on port ${PORT}`);
    })

    app.get('/messages', (req, res) => {
        res.send(messages)
    })

    app.post('/messages', (req, res) => {
        messages.push(req.body)
    })
```